# Android: dynamically add buttons to layout

Tags: android, button, android-relativelayout

I am trying to dynamically add 2 `buttons` to my `relative layout`. I want it to look like this:

[image]

but it currently looks like this:

[image]

With @Abdallah Alaraby's help:

```
    myButton1 = new Button(this);
    myButton1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.button);
    myButton1.setText("bttn1");

    myButton2 = new Button(this);
    myButton2.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.button);
    myButton2.setText("bttn2");


    RelativeLayout rl = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.rl_dynamic_bttn);
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp1 = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

lp1.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT);
lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF, myButton2.getId());
rl.addView(myButton1, lp1);
rl.addView(myButton2, lp);
...
...

}
```

I tried all sort of different allignment options but nothing seems to be working. Anyone know how I can make this look like the first picture?

Is it possible that the issue is with `my_button2.getId()`? Maybe it's not recognized?

Comment: Better add both the buttons in your xml and set visibility to gone. Make it visible whenever required

Comment: You are setting your anchor view as the same (myButton2) for each of your views. But I also agree with @Indra that this would be easier done adding them in xml and using Visibility.

Comment: that's an interesting method but I want the buttons to be added based on user input. like if user enter 5, I add 5 buttons. Row 1 might have 5 buttons, row 2 might have 10 buttons, row 3 might have only 1 button... So I can't just make a ton of buttons invisible...it's a big waste of space...so i want to add dynamically

Comment: @zgc7009 so how do I fix it? Do I make a new anchor? or I make a new layout param for each button?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF, myButton2.getId());
rl.addView(myButton1, lp);
rl.addView(myButton2, lp);
```

You are using the same rule for both buttons, try the following:

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp1 = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

myButton1.setId(1)
lp1.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT);
lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF, myButton2.getId());
rl.addView(myButton1, lp1);
rl.addView(myButton2, lp);
```

If myButton2 does not have an assigned Id, the default Id would be -1 and it won't work. you have to use myButton2.setId(int) before using myButton2.getId()

Comment: thanks so much @Abdallah. you got me really close to the solution. Take a look at my original post. I edited it with your code and I added some pictures for explanations. Can you help me reach the desired layout?

Comment: You just have to use `ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT` instead of `ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT`, I have modified my answer to suit your needs

Comment: but it's still not working...It looks like the second picture just with my_button1 on the left side and my_button2 all the way on the right. they are still not side by side.

Comment: is it possible that myButton2.getId() isn't doing anything? I just guessed that part. Am I supposed to create its id somewhere?

Comment: Yes it is possible, If `myButton2` does not have an assigned Id, the default Id would be -1 and it won't work. you have to use `myButton2.setId(int)` before using `myButton2.getId()`

Comment: Oh, let me try that. (I re-edited the question above again) thanks for your help...

Comment: ya it works now. Thanks so much. Can you edit your code again with just adding myButton1.setId(1) (not my_button2) so I can give you full credit for the answer?